# Generate pseudo sample of population given probabilities

Tags: c, cocoa, random, distribution, sample

I would like to generate pseudo data that conforms to the distribution of actual sampled data. Looking for an efficient and accurate method in C/Obj-C for iphone development. Currently the occurrance of 60 different categories in 1000 sampled events has been assigned a probability (0-1). I want to generate 1000 new events which conform to the same probabilities.

#### *Clarification {*

I have a categorical distribution of set {1,2,...,60}. I understand that samples from this distribution will conform to the probabilities of each category. Therefore I need to take 1000 samples from this distribution. I have determined (thanks to answers so far) that I need to:

1. Normalize this distribution by summing the values and dividing each
   by the sum.
2. Order them.
3. Create a CDF by replacing each value with the sum of all previous values.
4. Then I can generate a uniform random number between 0 and 1, and find the greatest number in the CDF whose value is less than or equal to the number just chosen, and return the category corresponding to this CDF value.

   #### *}*

**Q1**. Is this the correct way to solve the problem?

**Q2**. The caveat still holds that I'm using NSDecimals to store the category probabilities. Are there any libraries available or functions in Cocoa or Math.h, etc. that I can use to do this simply? I'm open to trying new libraries, currently only have Core-Plot and the standard Cocoa libraries in this project. Thanks.

Comment: Your description is unclear.  Are you saying that you have an existing PDF (or at least, a histogram), and that you want to generate new random data that conforms to that PDF/histogram?

Comment: updated the question to further clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is unclear.  But it sounds like you're looking for [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Basically, you first need to generate a [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) corresponding to your original data; call it F(x).  You then generate uniform random data in the range 0->1, and then transform it using the inverse CDF, i.e F<sup>-1</sup>(x).

Comment: thank you. I have clarified my question yet again based on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion. This assumes that when you say "normalized probability" you mean the sum of the probability of all types is 1. (If not, you'll need to rescale so that's the case.)

- Make up some order for your 60 types. (Say, alphabetic.)
- Generate a random number between 0 and 1. (Call it your "target".)
- Create an accumulator, initially at 0.
- Loop through your 60 types. For each type:

  - Add the probability of that type of event to your accumulator.
  - If your accumulator is >= your target, generate an event of that type and stop.

If you do that 1000 times, I believe you'll get the distribution you're looking for.